# Can't Convert `for` Loop to `apply` Function

Tags: r, for-loop, sapply

I've converted `for` loops I've found in the past into `apply` functions e.g.:

```
y <- 6:10
z <- 1:5
for(i in 1:length(y)){
z[i] <- y[i] * y[i]^2
}
z

z <- sapply(X = 1:length(y), FUN = function(i){
y[i] * y[i]^2
})
z
```

But the following loop has been giving me issues today:

```
lambda <- 2.9
n <- 20
z <- 1:n
x <- 0.02
z[1] <- x
for(i in 1:(n - 1)){
  z[i + 1] <- lambda * z[i] * (1 - z[i])
  }
z

z <- 1:n
z[1] <- x
sapply(X = 1:(n - 1), FUN = function(i){
  lambda * z[i] * (1 - z[i])
  })
```

Does anyone see the bug?

Comment: have a look at `purrr:accumulate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need result from previous step (eg. z[i+1]=f(z[i] ), you can not use `sapply` which results are available at the end of all steps.

For this you can use `accumulate` from package `purrr`:

```
purrr::accumulate(1:(n-1), ~(lambda * . * (1 - .)), .init=x)
 [1] 0.0200000 0.0568400 0.1554667 0.3807608 0.6837678 0.6270652 0.6781778 0.6329327
 [9] 0.6737538 0.6374479 0.6702134 0.6409794 0.6673619 0.6437710 0.6650567 0.6459932
[17] 0.6631894 0.6477708 0.6616750 0.6491974
```

where ~ defines a function taking 2 parameters (. and .y), . being reinjected from previous step and .y is the next step value

To better understand try:

```
purrr::accumulate(1:n, ~.)
purrr::accumulate(1:n, ~.y)
```

Comment: That's great. Can you explain why I can't use `sapply` for this? This way I can avoid this problem in the future and understand why this wasn't working.

Comment: Could I use `rapply` in this situation?

Comment: no because mapply arguments are processed in parallel and none is reinjected. In basr R you could use `Reduce(function(x,y) (lambda * x * (1 - x)), 1:n, init=x, accumulate = T)`. But `purrr` is a great package fixing a lot of base R issues and I strongly encourage you to study it.